# How to insert rows at specific positions into a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age': 
[28,34,29,42]})
```

and another dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna', 'Susie'],'Age':[20,50]})
```

as well as a list with indices

```
pos = [0,2].
```

What is the most pythonic way to create a new dataframe df2 where df1 is integrated into df right before the index positions of df specified in pos?

So, the new array should look like this:

```
df2 = 
     Age   Name
0    20    Anna
1    28    Tom
2    34    Jack
3    50    Susie
4    29    Steve
5    42    Ricky
```

Thank you very much.

Best,

Nathan

Comment: Your indices specified in `pos` don't seem to match your desired output dataframe `df2`

Comment: The indices refer to the indices in df before which I want to insert the new rows. They are NOT the indices in df2. So, I want to insert a new row before index 0 (=Tom) and 2 (=Steve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are searching for is implemented by `numpy.insert`, however, this will not play very well with `pandas.DataFrame` objects, but no-matter, `pandas.DataFrame` objects have a `numpy.ndarray` inside of them (sort of, depending on various factors, it may be multiple arrays, but you can think of them as on array accessible via the `.values` parameter).

You will simply have to reconstruct the `columns` of your data-frame, but otherwise, I suspect this is the easiest and fastest way:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':
   ...: [28,34,29,42]})

In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna', 'Susie'],'Age':[20,50]})

In [4]: np.insert(df.values, (0,2), df1.values, axis=0)
Out[4]:
array([['Anna', 20],
       ['Tom', 28],
       ['Jack', 34],
       ['Susie', 50],
       ['Steve', 29],
       ['Ricky', 42]], dtype=object)
```

So this returns an array, but this array is exactly what you need to make a data-frame! And you have the other elements, i.e. the `columns` already on the original data-frames, so you can just do:

```
In [5]: pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, (0,2), df1.values, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
Out[5]:
    Name Age
0   Anna  20
1    Tom  28
2   Jack  34
3  Susie  50
4  Steve  29
5  Ricky  42
```

So that single line is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky solution with float indexes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age': [28,34,29,42]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna', 'Susie'],'Age':[20,50]}, index=[-0.5, 1.5])

result = df.append(df1, ignore_index=False).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
    Name  Age
0   Anna   20
1    Tom   28
2   Jack   34
3  Susie   50
4  Steve   29
5  Ricky   42
```

Pay attention to `index` parameter in `df1` creation. You can construct `index` from `pos` using simple list comprehension:

```
[x - 0.5 for x in pos]
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!